# Liquibase exclude schema name from changelog

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have a multi-tenant application. Each tenant has it's own schema in the database. All the schemas are logically the same, the only difference is the schema name (the actual schema).

I want to be able to run something `liquibase:update schemaName=my-schema` which would update the given schema.

My `changelogs.xml` look like this:

```
<createTable tableName="myTable" schemaName="${schemaName}">
```

where `schemaName` is parametrized, and obtained as a dynamic property. However, the problem is with this that the `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` tables only exist in the default schema, the one used for openning a connection to the database. I have this configured in `liquibase.properties`.

**liquibase.properties**

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/my-db?currentSchema=public
```

And now schema given as a parameter and schema defined in properties don't match, ie. schema given as a parameter doesn't have it's own `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock`, instead validates itself against these tables in `public` schema.

**Error**

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
[ERROR]      1 change sets check sum
[ERROR]           001-add-table-mytable.xml::001::wesleyy was: 7:fb1f721005e26807efc07bde45f459b9 but is now: 7:0722a27fccf7137a326a1e50685a22fc
```

Looks like the `schemaName` parameter changed the checkSum.

Is there a way to:

1. Somehow exclude `schemaName` from the checksum? OR
2. Dynamically generate `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` on each given `schemaName`?

Comment: Liquibase only use a single `databasechangelog` table. There is no need for multiple tables as the change log stores the changeset identifier and that is unique for each changeset (even if you split the changelog over multiple files) If you want to create that single table in a different schema you can do that using `defaultSchemaName`: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So how would you handle multiple schemas then? Because it reports the checkSum violation when you try to update on another schema...

Answer (score 1):

When running liquibase, use  optional parameter 
"--liquibaseSchemaName=[schemaName]"

Liquibase will to create/use changelog tables in [schemaName] instead of the default user you are connected to.

As each schema/tenant will have it's own copy of changelog there will not be any checksum issues caused by a change in the schema name.

Comment: how would you pass that option to a liquibase maven plugin?